# Сетевой мост и таблица маршрутизации

Tags: сеть

Привет, РутКод!

Я пытаюсь протолкнуть в своё мировоззрение понятие сетевого моста (не в аппаратной, а в программной реализации), но наталкиваюсь на следующие противоречия.

Сетевой мост служит для объединения двух или более сетей. Например мой компьютер подключен к локальной сети через `eth0` и к интернету через `wlan0`. Чтобы раздать интернет в локальную сеть я должен соединить мостом eth0 и wlan0. Но почему тоже самое не делает таблица маршрутизации? Раз у меня есть доступ к интернету, значит **в таблице маршрутизации есть запись, что все внешние пакеты следует направлять на `wlan0`. А значит пришедший из локальный сети и адресованный во вне пакет, по тем же правилам, что и генерированные мною, должен быть отправлен на `wlan0`.** И это без использования сетевого моста.

- Где я ошибся?
- Как в действительности сетевой мост вписывается в концепцию таблицы маршрутизации?

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае маршрутизации достаточно, когда маршрутизатор знает все окружающие сети. Например, если две сети 192.168.0.1/24 и 192.168.1.1/24 подключены к одному и тому же маршрутизатору.

Ваш же шлюз, скорее всего, знает интернет (wlan0) и знает вашу сеть (eth0). Но шлюзы, к которым он подключен дальше по цепочке знать вашу сеть не могут (без дополнительных настроек и пр.) А так как интернету знаком адрес вашего шлюза, то от него и к нему пакеты доставляться будут. В таком случае в его задачи должна входить еще и трансляция адресов.

Т.е. когда пакет инициирован в локальной сети (eth0), ваш маршрутизатор транслирует адрес отправителя в свой внешний адрес (wlan0). Если же пакет приходит к вам на маршрутизатор, он должен преобразовать адрес получателя со своего внешнего (wlan0) во внутренний - адрес компьютера, ожидающего пакет.

В свою очередь сетевой мост не является точкой маршрутизации (так как уровень 2 OSI, а для маршрутизации нужен 3й). Т.е. все, что приходит на ваш wlan0 отправляется на eth0, никакой маршрутизации не производится.